# Socket.io is working on Local Host but not Heroku

Tags: node.js, sockets, heroku, socket.io

I managed to get sockets to work on my LocalHost, however when uploading to Heroku I get the following errors.

Heroku logs:

```
2020-02-26T19:18:12.223451+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N22xsN8" host=evening-beach-84352.herokuapp.com request_id=9e085385-d06d-42f8-a02b-741ebdb50139 fwd="99.239.140.92" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=1156 protocol=https
2020-02-26T19:18:16.268249+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N22xtMN" host=evening-beach-84352.herokuapp.com request_id=560a1283-e9ad-4f98-b65d-c98e3af0d989 fwd="99.239.140.92" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=1156 protocol=https
2020-02-26T19:18:16.340518+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N22xtNI" host=evening-beach-84352.herokuapp.com request_id=0747c99f-bfa7-4a48-9dc9-396237ea4afd fwd="99.239.140.92" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=17ms status=404 bytes=417 protocol=https
2020-02-26T19:18:16.345722+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N22xtNd" host=evening-beach-84352.herokuapp.com request_id=c28aa30e-c33f-4d2b-809d-7f723c9ad2f8 fwd="99.239.140.92" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=1156 protocol=https
2020-02-26T19:18:16.394512+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N22xtOS" host=evening-beach-84352.herokuapp.com request_id=93635a58-6c21-4d1a-81b4-ba67c712bc4a fwd="99.239.140.92" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=417 protocol=https
2020-02-26T19:18:18.146871+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N22xtpq" host=evening-beach-84352.herokuapp.com request_id=8dc8077a-5719-4f97-bd60-dc2f9585efea fwd="99.239.140.92" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=1156 protocol=https
2020-02-26T19:18:18.104971+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N22xtp6" host=evening-beach-84352.herokuapp.com request_id=1a135498-5911-4757-90a6-52f22188b3ae fwd="99.239.140.92" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=1156 protocol=https
2020-02-26T19:18:18.174618+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N22xtqB" host=evening-beach-84352.herokuapp.com request_id=dce824bb-5243-45be-bd9b-5be3026412ac fwd="99.239.140.92" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=417 protocol=https
2020-02-26T19:18:18.235090+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N22xtr2" host=evening-beach-84352.herokuapp.com request_id=44dbc61d-5e40-4283-b602-77107c20bdcd fwd="99.239.140.92" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=404 bytes=417 protocol=https
```

Browser console logs:

```
polling-xhr.js:271 POST https://evening-beach-84352.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N22yWHd 404 (Not Found)
```

I have this set up on my client side code:

```
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";

const socket = socketIOClient("https://evening-beach-84352.herokuapp.com/")
```

And this one my server side code:

```
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const socketIO = require('socket.io')
const io = socketIO(server, { origin: "*:*" });

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
```

Comment: Hello, were you able to solve this problem? I enabled session affinity too. I am getting similar error.  heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?transport=polling host=myawesomeapp.herokuapp.com request_id=5f15281e-14ff-461e-aadc-db3a8243e7ae fwd="73.202.145.46" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=400 bytes=195 protocol=https

Comment: If you see above error... you would see "polling", but I did not add polling at all to the Socket.io options.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled session affinity in your app? From the [support article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets):

> Apps using Socket.io should enable session affinity. If you plan to
>   use Node’s Cluster module or to scale your app to multiple dynos, you
>   should also follow Socket.io’s multiple-nodes instructions.
>
> ```
> heroku features:enable http-session-affinity
> ```

Comment: I just added that, however no luck. I'm still getting the same 404. In my Heroku logs, it shows the GET requests have status of 200, but the POST requests have the 404 status. So it seems my GET requests are reaching the server but not my POSTs?

Answer (score 0):

I just started using Heroku recently and just added socket.io to my application and am seeing similar errors.  Yesterday they went away, today they are back.  I have two tabs in my browser 1 works the other doesn't...

The difference:  http vs https

When you click the link in Heroku to take you to your app it navigates to https://myapp.herokuapp.com but if I manually navigate to http://myapp.herokuapp.com suddenly all the errors go away.

Now I'd like to know the reason why one works and the other doesn't...